# Multiple dropzone instance in one HTML form

Tags: jquery, multithreading, dropzone.js

I have a classical HTML form on my web page and three instances of dropzone.

I use `$.ajax` for post data from HTML form and in `success` method I checked result, if form success I run dropzone `processQueue`  for uploading files from three instances. But I do not know when `processQueue` finish, for redirection that page to another.

I think solve is using `jquery.when()` but I do not have idea how to implement it :/

Comment: JS is single threaded :) so I wouldn't include multithreading, anyways show code you tried :)

Comment: I know ;), but must exits solution for my problem. I'm not first person in the world with this problem :)

Comment: Dropzone has events you can utilize such as "sending": just before files are sent to the server, "complete": Called when the upload was either successful or erroneous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution.

I use dropzone `oncomplete` trigger for waiting complete and make a three global variable for checking is true/false, like this:

```
var first_complete = false;
var second_complete = false;
var third_complete = false;
function doSomething(thread_name) {
    if(thread_name == 'first') {
        first_complete = true;
    }

    if(thread_name == 'second') {
        second_complete = true;
    }

    if(thread_name == 'third') {
        third_complete = true;
    }

    if(first_complete && second_complete && third_complete) {
        window.location.replace('new_url');
    }
}
```